# Is it possible to have multiple applications listening to the same com port?

Tags: c#, port

Is there something like read-only mode for the COM Port, so there can be multiple applications listening to it? If there is, how do I do it in C#?

Comment: I think when an application start to listen to a port , so another application can not use it or open it again

Comment: It is not possible, only one process can get the port opened.  Everybody else will get access denied.  This is otherwise made possible by filter drivers, they can snoop on the device driver traffic.  You'll need to go shopping if you want one.